# 400 Bad Request with a $http.post that does not contains a body

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I have an angular js application, and when trying to issue the following post request :

```
$resource('api/'+API_VERSION+'/projects/:projectId/users/:userId')
  .save(
          {
           projectId:$scope.project.id,
           userId:id
         },
         {}
         ,function(){
        // Handle callback
       });
```

I get a 400 bad request error.
the request is handled by a spring RestController and the method looks like the following :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{projectId}/users/{userID}",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @RolesAllowed(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
  void addUsers(@PathVariable Long projectId, @PathVariable Long userId) {
    log.debug("REST request to add admin to project");
    projectService.addUser(projectId, userId);
  }
```

I Checked the request that is been sent to the server, and nothing bad strikes me.

The url is correct (all parameter are of valid type), and the content type is set to Application json.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Your API consumes JSON and returns void, so I think you should have `consumes = MediaType.APPLICAT_JSON_VALUE` in your `@RequestMapping`.

[Edit]:

Apart from the consumes annotation everything is fine with your back-end. Can you try making your post request with the following code :

```
$resource('api/'+API_VERSION+'/projects/:projectId/users/:userId',
    {projectId: $scope.project.id, userId: id}).$save();
```

or again, creating an instance of the resource :

```
var Project = $resource('api/'+API_VERSION+'/projects/:projectId/users/:userId',
    {projectId: $scope.project.id, userId: id});

var newProject = new Project();
newProject.$save();
```

And let me know if it worked ?

Comment: first of all thank you for answer, i tried that but i didn't solve my problem. i'm guessing the problem come from my client's request and not the server because the functional test work fine , for instance the following call works fine :  restProjectResourceMock.perform(post("/api/" + Application.API_VERSION + "/projects/" + projectDTO.getId() + "/users/" + user.getId()))
      .andExpect(status().isOk());   and the user if correctly added to the project

Comment: Hey, I've edited my answer with some suggestions for your post request. I hope it will do the trick.

Comment: again thank you very much :), that was not the actual problem but finally i figure it out, it was because in my backend the userID is written with and uppercase I and D while in the param it's juste Id , so once i made sure it's the same it worked fine

Comment: Aaah yes right I see it now ! Damn sometimes we should just look for the simplest explanations. I'm sorry I missed it !